# Is there a simple way to preview the files that rm will remove?

Tags: rm

Is there a simple way to evaluate what a given `rm` command will do when you do not understand it (such as not recognizing how the flags, variables, etc. interact)?

While `ls` helps catch problems in your `rm` parameters, `ls -abc XYZ` does not list the same files that would be affected by `rm -abc XYZ`. Ideally, I would like to type something like `previewrm -abc XYZ` and see what would be removed without actually removing anything, including using the `-f` flag.

I essentially want to run `rm` in test batch mode. That is, I want to see what actions it would take if it was run for real, preferably without touching it at all. Thus, `testout 'rm -abc XYZ'` might be the true ideal.

Comment: `echo rm -abc XYZ` shows you which files and directories will be directly affected. Do you want to see the directory contents? Or do you want to know what cannot be deleted (due to access rights)?

Comment: Ideally, I would like to see directory contents and also how access rights affect the outcome, but echo does meet some of the need. It catches things like `rm $FOO/*` and `rm *(1)*`.

Comment: If you want to run `rm` in test batch mode, i.e. showing what actions it would take if it was run for real (which is what I think you want) then you should say so more explicitly. Two people have suggested `rm -i`, which I don't think does what you want.

Comment: The answers suggesting the `-i` flag are the best I've seen before. I recognize that they might be the best answer there is, but my hope was for something that didn't require touching the flags. While I'm smart enough to pull out the `-f`, I'm looking to avoid slip-ups like `rm -i -f`. That is, adding the `-i` flag is not sufficient; you also have to pull the `-f` and `--force`.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D The possible duplicate has an accepted answer that I would not have accepted. The answer from Alexis gets at the point that rm doesn't really provide a dry-run, nor do the other answers take into account the user's rights.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *simple* way is to use `rm -i` the way @orion describes. If you want something that will not remove anything but doesn't tweak rm's flags, you can always **build your own version** of `rm`, let's call it `preview-rm`. It's really pretty straightforward, and you can even do it without touching the actual `rm` source files:

1. Find the source to your system's version of `rm`. You may need to download a source package, or whatever. GNU `rm` is part of the "core utilities" and consists of two C files, `rm.c` and `remove.c`, and several header files. Once you are set up to compile system utilities, the rest is trivial.
2. Create the file `mockrm.c` with the following contents. The only non-trivial part is that some versions of `rm` detect directories by trying to `unlink()` them and checking for error, so we need to ensure this works correctly:

   ```c
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <errno.h>

   int unlink(char *s)
   {
       struct stat sbuf;
       lstat(s, &sbuf);
       /* Simulate unlink error if we're asked to unlink a directory. */
       if (S_ISDIR(sbuf.st_mode)) {
           return EISDIR;
       }

       puts(s);
       return 0;
   }    

   int rmdir(char *d)
   {
     printf("%s (dir)\n", d);
     return 0;
   }
   ```
3. Finally, compile your `preview-rm` executable like this:

   ```
   % cc rm.c remove.c mockrm.c -o preview-rm
   ```

   The functions in `mockrm.c` will be linked in precedence to the system calls provided by the C library, giving you a toothless clone of `rm` that you can use for preview. (Do test that it really works before you point it at important files.)

**Alternative:** If you're on a system that supports the [`LD_PRELOAD` feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick) (OS X doesn't), you might be able to get the same effect by compiling *mockrm.c* into a shared library (`.so`) and forcing it to be loaded by the real `rm`:

```bash
% LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/mockrm.so rm -flags files
```

But since you need to change the command invocation anyway, why not just create a separate executable as shown above. I know it'd be a little nervous pointing the real `rm` at valuable files (**Edit:** and if you update your OS, you'd have to test again and make sure `rm` hasn't changed in a way that disabled the wrapper.)

Comment: Relying on all versions of rm to use no OS functions other than unlink and rmdir, under all circumstances, seems very unwise.  I *might* trust that, if the utility came from the same release, from the same maintainers, as rm itself, but ONLY if I knew they also had very good QA practices.

Comment: Do you know another system call that can remove a file? System calls are not designed to be redundant. But like I said, by all means inspect the source and test the result. `rm` (even GNU `rm`) is not that large a program.

Comment: This is the current `rm` source, right? http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/rm.c

Comment: @user63051, how would I know? You haven't said which Unix distribution you are running. Your best bet is probably to get the source using your system's package manager. That said, this is _not_ the place to find out how to do that-- it's a big topic. Look into your package manager's documentation or tutorials.

Comment: @alexis: sorry. I was just going off of your comment about GNU `rm` not being a large program. I actually quite like your approach here, even if it's pretty clear that what I thought might exist does not.

Comment: But isn't it even more satisfying if you can make it yourself? :-) Anyway that looks like GNU `rm` all right, and it's pretty small (though more than half the code is in `remove.c`).

Comment: @alexis: unlinkat is one such function, but that's kind of missing the point.  The point is that, at any time, the implementation of rm could change, and you should not rely on it having a particular implementation, when missing any given method of implementation could be catastrophic, as is the case here.  The PROPER way to solve this is to submit a patch to rm which implements a dry-run mode.  The half-assed solution is to distribute your own version of rm, with a known implementation, along with a known-good wrapper for that version. Any less than that is just dangerous.

Comment: @Lee, I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing. Who said anything about distributing? You're right that the second method (.so wrapper) would be vulnerable to a sudden reimplementation of `rm`, however unlikely this is.  I did say I couldn't really trust it. But building and using your own modified version of a program is the very heart of Free Software. (I do agree that sharing your work is also right up there.)

Comment: @Alexis: Well,distributing is a *slightly* poor choice of words.  What I'm saying is that you'd have to maintain your own version -- your own distribution, if you like.  But we seem to mostly agree, so I'll stop making the point now.  Sounds like you get the issues OK :)

Answer (score 35):

You could use `rm -i` to be prompted for every single file it will remove. You can pipe `no` into it repeatedly, (confusingly) using the `yes` command, to just view prompts (rejecting all of them):

```
yes no | rm -i files/globs/options
```

EDIT in response to comments by @user63051

If you are concerned about dangerous flag combinations, you can specify
`rm -i --` and anything after that will NOT be treated as an option. This of course means that for the `-r` flag to work, you need to put it before `--`.

Another suggestion, if you want to try it, is to create a `dummy` user that doesn't belong to any of the existing groups. If the `others` permissions of your files don't include `write` permission (they usually don't unless you specifically want that), you can just login as the other user (`su dummy`) and do the `rm` command. It won't have permissions to delete anything so it will simply complain about it. You can also do this to use the suggestion above (as double protection).

I should warn you that all the options that call `rm` are a bit dangerous. I usually just prefix the entire command I want to run with `echo` to see what arguments will bash give to the command (how it expands the wildcards and which files it finds). Then just remove `echo` if everything looks fine. Notice that this won't list contents of recursively found files with `-r` but you will see the directory it wants to destroy.

In essence - use `echo` if you want to see what it does. Use `--` for protection from runaway flags. Use `-i` just in case, it will ask about every file and you will notice if it asks about something you don't want to remove. Only if you really want to produce a list, one file per line, it makes sense to do anything else.

Comment: `yes no` has to be the most humorous command I've seen today...

Comment: How about [`if yes and no`](http://utumno.github.io/blog/2015/05/17/if-yes-and-no/) then ? :D

Answer (score 6):

When I want to do this, I use 'find' as a wrapper around rm.  This is better (for the use case you have in mind) because:

- It's more flexible in terms of matching multiple patterns
- It can handle more filenames than a shell wildcard in subdirs (*/*.tmp etc.)
- You can do everything rm can do, since it wraps rm, but more besides, such as printing the entire rm command.
- It doesn't call rm too often, when you use + (rather than ;) as part of the -exec args, so it's not really much less efficient than just running rm.

To list files to you might want to delete:

```
find . -name \*.tmp
```

To preview deletion:

```
find . -name \*.tmp -exec echo rm \{\} +
```

To actually delete them, just remove the 'echo':

```
find . -name \*.tmp -exec rm \{\} +
```

Or, you can do more advanced search/delete commands, like this one:

```
find . \( -name \*.tmp -o -iname cache -o -iname temp \) -exec rm \{\} +
```

You can also just pipe the output of find into "xargs rm", but use NULs to separate filenames, like so:

```
find . -name \*.tmp -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: This is definitely getting at one of my two implicit use cases. When I'm trying to be careful about what I'm removing, I might switch to using `find` as suggested. When I run across an `rm` command that I don't understand, I'll probably try the `yes no | rm -i` option.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `i` switch. See `man rm`:

> -i     prompt before every removal

Comment: `man` answers are the best answers. Simple, and verifiable. It always makes more sense to me to ask the computer what it knows than to ask the internet what my computer knows.

Comment: @mikeserv Of course, nowadays the Internet *does* know what your computer knows... :)

Comment: Probably the NSA is hip anyway. I'll give you that.

Comment: I'm sure my question is unclear, but I definitely check `man` before asking questions, and I was hoping for a way to preview `rm` results without having to touch the flags, in part so that I can copy-paste the flags+parameters without relying on myself to accurately add and remove flags in each direction.

Comment: @user63051 The whole point of the `-i` switch, as I see it, is that your don't have to reissue the command...

Answer (score 4):

If not using the `-r` option, then you can list the files with

```
ls -ld <parameters>
```

or your favorite combination of `ls` options, as long as it includes `-d`. The discrepancy between the command line arguments and what `ls` shows is that if one of the arguments is a directory, `ls` shows its contents.

If you just want to list the names, `echo <parameters>` will do, or if you prefer them on separate lines:

```
printf '%s\n' <parameters>
```

This list is ambiguous in case a file name contains a newline; this is a concern for automated processing but not when you know that the files weren't produced by a potentially hostile party.

If using the `-r` option, call `find` to traverse the directories recursively:

```
find <parameters>
```